# bootstrap-ui modal with angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm facing the following problem: When I try to instantiate a modal

```
angular.module('previewApp')
  .controller('DienstleisterCtrl', function (dienstleisterRegObjService, staticDataService, $uibModal) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dienstleisterTypen = staticDataService.getDienstleisterTypen();
    vm.modRegObj = function (dienstleistertyp) {
      dienstleisterRegObjService.vorselektiertesProdukt.typ = vm.dienstleisterTypen[dienstleistertyp];
      var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'scripts/angular/modals/templates/regform.html',
        controller: 'RegFormCtrl as vm'
      });
    };
  });
```

it throws in the modal controller

```
angular.module('previewApp')
  .controller('RegFormCtrl', function (**$uibModalInstance**, dienstleisterRegObjService, staticDataService, fieldValidator) {    
});
```

the error:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $uibModalInstanceProvider <-
>   $uibModalInstance <- RegFormCtrl

This is the modal:
It has two forms, one nested in the other.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-right: 0px;">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close-modal">
      <div class="lr">
        <div class="rl">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="form-horizontal" ng-form="regForm">
              <fieldset>
                <legend class="text-center">
                  <div class="panel formular-head">
                    <h3 class="formular-title">Registrieren</h3>
                    <p class="text-muted formular-description"></p>
                  </div>
                </legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="organisation">Organisation</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="organisation" name="organisation" type="text" placeholder="z.B. Muster Catering GmbH" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="vm.regObj.organisation" ng-readonly="vm.orgReadOnly" ng-change="vm.checkValue('org')" ng-required="!vm.orgReadOnly">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="vorname">Vorname</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="vorname" name="vorname" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="vm.regObj.vorname" ng-readonly="vm.nameReadOnly" ng-change="vm.checkValue('name')" ng-required="!vm.nameReadOnly">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nachname">Nachname</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="nachname" name="nachname" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="vm.regObj.nachname" ng-readonly="vm.nameReadOnly" ng-change="vm.checkValue('name')" ng-required="!vm.nameReadOnly">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="max@muster.ch" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="vm.regObj.mail" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="vm.getMailChecker();">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="natio">Nationalität</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select id="natio" name="nationalitaet" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.regObj.nationalitaet">
                      <option ng-value="vmnat" ng-repeat="vmnat in vm.nationalitaeten">{{vmnat}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sprache">Sprache</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <select id="sprache" name="sprache" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.regObj.sprache">
                      <option ng-value="vmsprache" ng-repeat="vmsprache in vm.sprachen">{{vmsprache}}</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group produkt-katalog" ng-show="!vm.regObj.produkte.length == 0">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label produkt-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="" ng-repeat="vmprod in vm.regObj.produkte track by $index">
                      <produkt-item produkt="vmprod"></produkt-item>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div ng-form="produktForm">
                  <div class="formular-together panel shadowed">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dienstleistertyp">Dienstleistung</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <select id="dienstleistertyp" name="dienstleistertyp" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.vorselektiertesProdukt.typ" ng-required="vm.regObj.produkte.length == 0">
                          <option ng-value="vmtyp" ng-repeat="vmtyp in vm.typen">{{vmtyp}}</option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="produkt">Produkt</label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input id="produkt" name="produkt" type="text" placeholder="z.B. Lautsprecher, Dekoration, Helfer, Stilrichtung" class="form-control input-md" ng-model="vm.vorselektiertesProdukt.produkt" ng-required="vm.regObj.produkte.length == 0 || vm.vorselektiertesProdukt.typ !== ''">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-md-4"></label>
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right" name="submit" ng-click="vm.addProduct()" ng-disabled="produktForm.$invalid || vorselektiertesProdukt.produkt == ''">Hinzufügen</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="pull-right">
                      <button id="abbrechen" name="abbrechen" class="btn btn-default">Abbrechen</button>
                      <button id="registrieren" name="registrieren" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="regForm.$invalid || regObj.produkte.length == 0" ng-click="vm.registrieren()">Registrieren</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal Ende -->
```

In the app.js ui-bootstrap is declared, also in the index.html.

```
angular
  .module('previewApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngResource',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngMessages',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngToast'
  ]);

<script src="/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/bower_components/ngToast/dist/ngToast.js"></script>
```

This problem gives me headache, cause I know it's just a little fault, but in the last hours i tried nearly everything an nothing changed.

Help is very appreciated. I'll post an plunkr in the answers...

Comment: no dependency of jquery and bootstrap.js is required to use bootstrap-ui.. try to remove it

Comment: @Ore I'm wondering why you have uibModalInstance written like this `**$uibModalInstance**`, it's not good practice. Your error is very obvious and it says that your controller can't find a provider named `$uibModalInstance`. There are few things you can do for this. Make sure that you have correct provider name and secondly you can inject that provider like this `.controller('RegFormCtrl', [your provider here], function(your provider here){}.

Comment: @Rafael doesn't make any difference : /

Comment: @Amir The stars are just there cause i tried to highlight it for a better overview. Is your example written with the correct syntax? I tried ".controller('RegFormCtrl', ['provider', function()])" cause this is according to https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=$modalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20$modalInstance%20%3C-%20RegFormCtrl the correct syntax. Although I gonna try it with your example.

Comment: @Ore correction to my syntax regarding injection, I tried to edit it but it was late. So here's the correct syntax `.controller('RegFormCtrl', ['your provider here', function(your provider here){ //.... your code here }]);`. Take a look this [AngularJS Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: @Rafael Doesnt make any difference. With "ui.bootstrap" it also injects all nested modules like .carousel or .modal.

Comment: @Amir Also tried this. Its alwas the same err
Could it be caused by the "controller as vm" syntax that i uor.se in the modal itself? or does it probably have problems with nested forms? Before i created the modal with just bootstrap.js an this worked well, besides some bugs with mobile devices.

Comment: which version of `ui.bbotstrap`? Have you included it's dependency while bootstrapping the file?? As in something like, `angular.module('previewApp', ['ui.bootstrap'])` ??

Comment: @SudhansuChoudhary already checked versions. "angular": "~1.4.7", "angular-bootstrap": "~0.14.3". What do you mean with "while bootstrapping the file"? My app.js looks like i that i posted in my question. Btw. I use "/bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"

Comment: @Ore sorry see your app.js.. all fine, never mind!! Anyways try this, inject `$uibModal` in 'DienstleisterCtrl' and change the variable name in `controller: 'RegFormCtrl as vm'` from 'vm' to something else. Wonder, because you have nested forms and same alias names for two of the controllers, you are running into issues!!

Comment: I tried renaming the controller as and the view, but it didnt change anything. now i've tried with replacing the controller name with $scope and so on, but it didnt work also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK... I've no idea why or how it works but it does.

I did the following:

- I changed "controller as" in creating modal plus removed named controllers from my index.html and replaced them by $scope.
- I added in dienstleister.js, where the modal is beeing created, the modalinstance.result.then functions

Now there is no error anymore. If someone has an idea why it now works i would appreciate an explanation.

Thanks for your time guys.